# Sign in with apple sign in twice with two npm packages

Tags: angular, firebase, capacitor, apple-sign-in, nonce

I have an Angular app with Capacitor. I need to implement Apple sign in.

STEP 1
I have managed to make it work with the following package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@capacitor-firebase/authentication

STEP 2
I need to then also sign in with the web SDK from the package below:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/fire

It is here that i have errors and cannot fix. I get the error: "auth/missing-or-invalid-nonce"

QUESTION:
So my question is simple. How can i also sign in with the npm package in STEP 2?

```
  import { OAuthProvider } from '@angular/fire/auth';
  import { FirebaseAuthentication } from '@capacitor-firebase/authentication';

  AppleAuth() {
    //STEP 1
    FirebaseAuthentication.signInWithApple({}).then((result) => {
      if (result.credential?.accessToken) {
        //STEP 2
        const credential = new OAuthProvider('apple.com').credential({
          idToken: result.credential.idToken,
          rawNonce: 'What to put here?',
        });
        signInWithCredential(getAuth(), credential)
          .then((userCredential) => {
            // Never gets here!
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            //Error: auth/missing-or-invalid-nonce
          });
      }
    });
  }
```

ERROR: auth/missing-or-invalid-nonce

Here is the result i get from STEP 1:

{"credential":{"nonce":"CaZX9c9VeTByT3DsC9iPjarzzrmGKImN","authorizationCode":"c650b3ff44b7f4bf9921ca4ee8f44cb76.0.rzuw.Bg7CPK8kMkaVY4DxbCuQug","idToken":"eyJrae6TOiJZdXlYb1kiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2FwcGxlaWQuYXBwbGUuY29tIiwiYXVkIjoiY29tLnRhZ2Fsb25nbWVtb3JpZXMuYXBwIiwiZXhwIjoxNjc4NzAxODQzLCJpYXQiOjE2Nzg2MTU0NDMsInN1YiI6IjAwMDk0Ni5mZDNmOTkxZDQ2N2Q0ZDU5ODllN2VlMWRlY2Y3OTI1Mi4xNjE3Iiwibm9uY2UiOiIwNTAyMjFlMWZiZmUwM2I5MDAzMDM4NmJkNTVjN2U3M2IyOTZrO2A4YWI4ZjU4YjY2MTc1MTY0YjgyYzZkNDEyIiwiY19oYXNoIjoiX3ZUWEFpQVltMExjMk1YZnIzUXZXQSIsImVtYWlsIjoibmF0dXJ0YXR0YXN0ZXN0QGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsImVtYWlsX3ZlcmlmaWVkIjoidHJ1ZSIsImF1dGhfdGltZSI6MTY3ODYxNTQ0Mywibm9uY2Vfc3VwcG9ydGVkIjp0cnVlfQ.xs_F1ct3kltopkm91RwI5y9scxHVnHcQRNBGW5VRqE4ckiPpKHvBQiShrktafvj_YHLV5augk-LdzBeKy2L1mzHW7pYn4DGk7yP8Iv-xlZvj2VHlsvV8Scp4LDgzmpW2h2-7qJnd5cSKPsfz-O8WazKm85qaWqp7uDojIl4lQIJ_TIuslADLhGNNolRtEHlRGh-rLb14UpfiyiBOQKNoDE4ZW_xugAfWoJF5nXfv2OpcziMxMy6du8Zx2YNYnEXQFajS_IjX4f5jcmQ57xu8Z2gBF1zDtZox8x64yWm_Mc6tk-OJsH5IWizTCmUSX7NPoeI6E_0ixQL2vs_H5MZLnA","providerId":"apple.com"},"user":{"isAnonymous":false,"uid":"4VDDuFUxrhc3TIDTvo87yQlSp0p1","emailVerified":true,"providerId":"Firebase","displayName":"My name","email":"gmail"},"additionalUserInfo":{"providerId":"apple.com","isNewUser":false,"profile":{"iat":1678615442,"aud":"com.example.app","nonce":"050221e1fbfe03b90030386bd55c7e73b296ba08ab8f58b66175164b82c6d412","email":"gmail","nonce_supported":true,"sub":"000946.fd3f991d467d4d5989e7ee1decf79252.1616","exp":1678501842,"c_hash":"_vTXAiAYm0La2MXfr3QvWC","email_verified":"true","iss":"https://appleid.apple.com","auth_time":1678615442}}}

Answer (score 0):

Apple Sign-In works on Android and iOS only with skipNativeAuth=true (see [here](https://github.com/capawesome-team/capacitor-firebase/blob/main/packages/authentication/docs/firebase-js-sdk.md#quirks)):

```
const result = await FirebaseAuthentication.signInWithApple({ skipNativeAuth: true });
```

Comment: Perfect this was the solution!